# how to hide action bar only login and registration activities in android

Tags: java, android, mobile

how to hide action bar only login and registration activities.

i want to show action bar other all activities.

**getActivity().getActionBar().hide()** did not work.

Comment: Apply theme NoActionBar to Activity

Comment: post your android manifest file

Comment: create a theme in styles.xml

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks any research effort

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

</activity>
```

try this. Just set this theme on login and registration activity or you can set

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

Comment: @SupunPerera if any query feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

Add this manifest.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by settings `android:theme="@android:style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` to your login activity in Android MAnifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Please create

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

in styles.xml

Answer (score 0):

create a theme in styles.xml

```
 <style name="Theme.NoActionbar" parent="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

and apply this theme to the actiivities where you want to hide action bar inside manifest like this

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/Theme.NoActionbar">

</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi please make your new custom theme in `style.xml` or use predefine theme which does not have action bar after that put that theme in `android manifest.xml` in login and registration Activity like this

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="your theme">
</activity>

 <activity android:name=".RegistrationActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="your theme">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with 
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide();